# What is the cause of head gasket failure between cylinders?

Tags: cylinder-head, gasket

I have 4 cylinder Renault Clio gasoline car with 150 000 km. I had my head gasket replaced, because it blew between cylinders(rough idle,..)

It was cheap job, new gasket held nicely, but then some similar problems began to show up, they are not so intense, but I dont know.

There is very little of sputtering when accelerating, just a tiny amount and tiny specific noise if I go uphill under heavy load. Ignition coil, spark plugs, air, fuel filter, oil, fuel pump were replaced not long ago. I am guessing it could be fuel injector fault? Is that the reason gasket blew between cylinders and not elsewhere? There are many different types of head gasket failure. But I am not mechanic, I ask you? What would you say, why does gasket blow between cylinders? The head is from aluminum. Cooling system is all right all the time, no sludge, it was between cylinders. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple possibilities but the most common are:

1. Warped head or cylinder block
2. Defect in the cylinder head casting or the block casting
3. Defective head gasket
4. Improper cylinder head bolt torque

Answer (score 1):

The basic and most common way for you to blow a head gasket is for there to be either a warped head or a warped deck on the block. The head gasket themselves can give way, but that is much rarer. This also depends on the type of block it is, because some blocks have very little space between the cylinders, which means there is very little head gasket.

If your car is exhibiting the same type of symptoms again, I'd suggest you probably have some warped metal in there some place. If untended for too long, the combustion gasses going between cylinders can actually wear on the casting of both the head and the block, so it's good to get it taken care of.

Answer (score -1):

"There is very little of sputtering when accelerating, just a tiny amount and tiny specific noise if I go uphill under heavy load"

Sounds like a pistons slap to me ..
you could hear it tapping 1500-2000rpm and disappears on higher revs while being stationary and during load you could hear it till you lift off the gas.
That is indeed a piston slap